# Append the values if it is more than something

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to append the number in A to 5 if it is more than 5.

A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

To something like this:

A = [1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,5]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `map`

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
list(map(lambda x: x if x<5 else 5, A))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `min` function to take the smaller of each list item and 5:

```
[min(i, 5) for i in A]
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/InsidiousDigitalIntegrationtesting